# How to copy from const char* variable to another const char* variable in C?

Tags: c, char, memcpy, strcpy

I have a string constant that is assigned to a variable, like this:

```
const char* a = "Programming";
```

And I want to copy it to another variable of `const char*`, something like:

```
const char* b;
```

Here, I have tried `memcpy()` and `strcpy()`; it's not working, because in `memcpy` and `strcpy`, the destination variable should be `char*` instead of `const char*`. How do I get a copy of a `const char*`?

Comment: `const char* a = "Programming"; const char *b = a;` works. Both will point to the same string.

Comment: Please [edit] and show some of your relevant code instead of describing it.

Answer (score 3):

move the pointer ?

```
int main(){
    const char* a = "Programming";
    const char* b;

    //copy a to b
    b = a;

    printf("%s\n", b);


}
```

Comment: They will both point to the same memory, so technically it is *copy* instead of *move*.